# open file MS-Word, and MS-Excel in web browser using Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are displaying uploaded files in grid. As of now all MS-Word, Excel and MS-PowerPoint Presentation files are getting downloaded automatically in browser when user clicks on it.  Now how do we open uploaded file (like MS-Word, Ms-Excel, MS-PowerPoint) in browser for reading and editing like Google Drive. Do we have solution to open file in browser, instead of downloading? Give any suggestions regarding this.

Comment: C#? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes i am trying with ASP.Net,C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be with an ActiveX control, but this would only work in Internet Explorer.

Here is an example I found for ASP.NET:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404688/Word-Excel-ActiveX-Controls-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

using OpenXml.

1. Upload file to server.
2. User third-side solution to convert Docx to Html. [Google](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=c%23%20openxml%20docx%20to%20html).
3. Return resulting markup to client in textarea.
4. Use WYSIWYG to make changes. [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) for example.
5. After upload modified markup to server use p.2 шт reversed order.
6. PROFIT))

Comment: anyway thanks for replying solution, but this will not use to me.is there any other solution in asp code instead of xml.